# VBA Excel Macro Run-time error '1004' when trying to .Find()

Tags: vba, excel

i am new to macro, and wanted to find a text or part of text from a range in a worksheet, i researched and found this code:

```
Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:="Custom ", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

But when i run, it gives me 1004 error. So this is my full sub:

```
Sub kl()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("te-dhenat")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:="Custom ", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            aCell.Value = "Test"
        Else
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        End If
    End With 

End Sub
```

i think the code looks good, so i don't know why excel is showing this error, please help, and thank you in advance

Comment: Code looks ok. What line is it failing on?

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Comment: @brettdj, its failing on Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(.....

Comment: @Rory no the sheet is not protected, pls help

Comment: As @brettdj said, there's nothing wrong with the code as written.

Comment: This is the first function, which calls kl():                       
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)     
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C300")) Is Nothing Then
    kl                                                                                       
 End If                                                                                  
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code

```
aCell.Value = "Test"
```

will cause the event code to execute again!

Please see [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) page, look for the section "Preventing Event Loops".

If has other info that is worth reading.

So adding code similar this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it and it perfectly worked, thank you very much